# Function with multiple model conditional returns false but after evaluate each condition in the function returns true in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, boolean

I have a model that has many associations and I have a function that verifies if is destroyable by validating that all associations are empty.

```
def destroyable?
  entries.empty? && splits.empty? && payment_terms_from.empty? && payment_terms_to.empty?
end
```

When calling this function the returned value is FALSE, but after evaluating each condition the returned value is TRUE. I performed some tests through the console:

```
irb(main):005:0> acc.destroyable?
=> false
irb(main):006:0> acc.entries
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
irb(main):007:0> acc.splits
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
irb(main):008:0> acc.payment_terms_from
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
irb(main):009:0> acc.payment_terms_to
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
irb(main):016:0> acc.destroyable?
=> true
```

The issue is that the destroy button in my view is not being display when it should be. Is this a problem related to cache? How can it be fixed?

Comment: I don't know Rails, so I really should keep my mouth shut, but I'm wondering if your problem might be related to [empty?](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/empty%3F). I'll delete this comment when I figure you've seen it.

Comment: The code that you have shown should work in the way that you expect. The console result is very strange and I'm thinking that there's something else in the code that you haven't shared that is causing a problem. The kind of coding error that might cause this is one of the methods `destroyable?`, `entries` etc. is overwritten, or defined twice.

Comment: My approach to this kind of problem is to write model tests to try to replicate the issue in the very controlled testing context.